# How can I reload two inactive tabs simultaneously via a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to reload two tabs that are next to each other. It works, but once I leave the tab (for instance, click another tab) or click elsewhere on the page, it stops refreshing. Why? I want it to keep refreshing those pages no matter where I click on the page or browser.

Here's my content.js

```
setInterval(function () {

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    var currentIndex = tabs[0].index;
    var leftIndex = tabs[0].index - 1;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {// This will return all tabs in current window
      chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[currentIndex].id);
      chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[leftIndex].id);
    });
  })

}, 2000);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>My cool extension</title>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're running content.js both inside the web page (where chrome.tabs.query fails with an error as it's not allowed there) and inside the browserAction popup which hides when you switch tabs. The correct solution would be to move the code into an event page script, see the documentation. You'll likely need messaging (see chrome.runtime API).

Comment: @wOxxOm I solved the issue using a different way, but thanks, I'm looking into it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed popup.html, added background part and it works right now. Here's the final script:

content.js

```
setInterval(function () {

  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
    var currentIndex = tabs[0].index;
    var leftIndex = tabs[0].index - 1;
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {// This will return all tabs in current window
      chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
      chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[1].id);
    });
  });

}, 2000);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": { "scripts": [ "content.js" ], "persistent": true },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```